# $.getJSON() not loading consistent data results

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have tried everything with the following jQuery code

```
$(this).ready(function(){   
    $.getJSON('json/summary.json?nocache=<?=md5(rand(1,50))?>', function(data) {

        var sold = data.sold;
        var price = data.averagePrice.toFixed(2);

    });
});
```

For some reason, the sold number - in the jquery page NOT summary.json - fluctuates incorrectly when I refresh or click around the page - it will give numbers lower than it should. I have no idea what to do. While I'm at it, what is the best way to prevent a cached page loads... guessing the above is not the best method.

BTW, summary.json returns something like:

{"sold":34,"averagePrice":133.0323529411764}

Thanks for any help. I have tried many things with no success.

Comment: there is absolutely no way that a variable will automatically change its value. please post you full code. where are you using sold and price and how

Comment: Thanks, you were correct. The issue was cache related and @ArunPJohny gave a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cache invalidating mechanism is not proper as it can return same value in multiple refreshes. You are using the md5 of a random num between 1 & 50 so multiple attempts can return the same random value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('json/summary.json?nocache=' + new Date().getTime(), function (data) {

        var sold = data.sold;
        var price = data.averagePrice.toFixed(2);

    });
});
```

---

Another option is to set the cache option globally for all jQuery ajax requests like

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false})
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('json/summary.json', function (data) {

        var sold = data.sold;
        var price = data.averagePrice.toFixed(2);

    });
});
```

---

But if you don't want to cache the particular resource value, then you can disable the cache from the server side by setting cache headers like `no-cache` and `no-store`

Comment: Thanks, caching was the problem.